# SOAPMessage writeTo without attachment

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee

I use [SOAPMessage.writeTo(OutputStream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html#writeTo%28java.io.OutputStream%29) to log web service messages. A problem is that it also writes attachments. It is space consuming and the binary attachments are not readable . Is there any way how to log the message without attachments, e.g. a wrapper?

There must be a better solution than this one.

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
message.writeTo(out);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(out.toString());

int indexOfAttachment = builder.indexOf("------=");
if (indexOfAttachment != -1) {
    return builder.substring(0, indexOfAttachment);
}

return builder.toString();
```

A sample message

```xml
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Header />
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:wsGetObjectByIDResponse
            xmlns:ns2="http://xxx.com/"
            xmlns:ns3="http://yyy.com/">
            <return>
                <serviceResponse status="OK" />             
                <contentData formatName="jpeg_lres"
                    objectContent="cid:e677f02c-002a-4c2c-8fd9-a3acdba5ad11@example.jaxws.sun.com"
                    objectName="Smlouva1.jpg" />
            </return>
        </ns2:wsGetObjectByIDResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
------=_Part_9_-806948376.1352979403086
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-ID: <e677f02c-002a-4c2c-8fd9-a3acdba5ad11@example.jaxws.sun.com>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
����\x00JFIF\x00\x00�\x00�\x00\x00��\x00C\x00
```

Comment: Yeah, kind of sad there is no better way...

Comment: It is not only that the attachments are not readable in my case the stream was consumed and later for the real extraction I only got -1 when accessing the stream...So it is better to avoid reading/printing any attachments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's actually a way to do this that is probably cleaner.

Here's my code :

```
// Get the Envelope Source 
Source src = message.getSOAPPart().getContent() ;

// Transform the Source into a StreamResult to get the XML
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
transformer.transform(src, result);
String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
```

Then you can log the xmlString, it corresponds to the Envelope part only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link to find your answer. http://ws.apache.org/axiom/quickstart-samples.html. Read the section Logging MTOM messages without inlining optimized binary data

Comment: Binary attachments come after the envelope, see my edited question.

Comment: Cant you use a Library like AXIOM to create the SOAP message and print it?

Comment: I just want to trim the binary data. I expected better SOAPMessage API.